# Intellij Idea - ignoring non-zero exit code of external tool

Tags: intellij-idea, run-configuration

I'm using [external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) to run `fuser -k 1099` command before actually launching my run configuration
[image: before launch]
But if external tool returns non-zero status, build configuration stops. That is perfectly correct, but I can not find any way to ignore failure. If it was a plain `bash`, I'd do something like `fuser -k 1099 || true`. But at Idea, that seems to be not possible

[image: external tool configuration]

Any ideas?

Comment: Wrap it into a bash script and always return zero exit code from it?

Comment: hm, it might work! Even without script, just by `bash -c 'fuser -k 1099'; true` . I did not think in this direction, expected Idea to provide some option to skip failure of external tool. Thanks!

Comment: If you post your comment as answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `/bin/bash` as the program and the following as the arguments:

```
-c 'fuser -k 1099'; true
```

This way the exit code of the tool will be always zero.

Comment: This was the only issue/solution I could find relevant to what I was running into trying to run a bash command in the external tool. 

However, defining: 
-c "<command> && <command>"; true

Would not work for me. IntelliJ kept putting the ";" inside the quotes for some reason... I had to individually set each command inside the quotes with a "; true" and then it worked.

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Same here under Windows, putting `cmd` in `Program` and `/c taskkill /IM my.exe /F & set errorlevel=0` in `Arguments` (if I run `cmd /c taskkill /IM my.exe /F & set errorlevel=0` in a command prompt I got error that my.exe does not run but `errorlevel` is actually `0`, but from IntelliJ it seems & is taken as a taskkill argument instead of the next command since I got `ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '&'. Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.`, I tried with call or putting a `if 1 == 1` before `taskkill /IM my.exe /F & set errorlevel=0` and some other things without success...

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer was not working for me (see my comment under it) I then found a solution that is to create a script that exits with 0, here under windows (let us call it `KillMyExeNoError.bat`):

```
taskkill /IM my.exe /F
exit /B 0
```

Then put `C:\Path\To\KillMyExeNoError.bat` in `Program` and leave `Arguments` empty.

Maybe under Linux you need to put `bash` in `Program` and `/path/to/script.sh` in `Arguments`.

Not the best solution since it would be good not to have to create a separate script but at least it works.